# How to create form elements from model or store in Extjs?

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs, extjs4

Is it possible to create entire form from model or from store in extjs. I have defined model and store but I do not want to define all fields again just to create form.

So is it possible to create form by just passing model class or store?

Comment: I don't know if something exists for that... but it shouldn't be that hard to write one if it doesn't.

Comment: Yeah I know but if I knew how to write that I would not ask a question on stackoverflow :) Do you know how to write one?

Comment: I'm sure it is possible. Just get the fields from the model/store, and create a form field for each one, and add them to a form.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I did to render a form based on a `GridPanel`'s column config. Maybe it can give you an idea where to start from.

```
 renderContactFormFields: function (window) {

    //In my case, the structure is such: Window->FormPanel->BasicForm->FieldSet
    //So I want to add fields within the fieldset...
    var fieldSet = window.down('form').down('fieldset');

    var fieldSetItem;

    //'fieldsToRender' is actually the 'columns' property of a GridPanel
    //that I simply put into a property of the window object to access it later
    for (var i = 0; i < window.fieldsToRender.length; i++) {

        var col = window.fieldsToRender[i];

        fieldSetItem = { name: col.dataIndex, fieldLabel: col.text };
        //A textfield in this case, but you could have rules to change the type of field you want to render...
        fieldSetItem.xtype = 'textfield';
        fieldSet.add(fieldSetItem);
    }

    //finally, load the record within the form...(selectedContact is the record that was selected in the GridPanel...)
    window.down('form').loadRecord(window.selectedContact);
}
```

So you could say that's generated from the model, which is tied to a store, which in turn is tied to a GridPanel.